# calculating image similarity of two "line drawing" images

Tags: java, android, image-processing, dct, image-comparison

I am developing an Android app for kids to learning writing letters, one function is to rate their drawing of the letters,I am stuck on how to determine whether the drawing is in good shape. What I am doing now is saving the drawing as a image and comparing with a image of the correct letter, I have tried Hanming distance and DCT algorithm but it seems too strict for my requirement, i.e. A drawing which would be considered acceptable give very large DCT value(indicating not similar at all)comparing to the correct one, and two different drawings of which one is definitely better than the other give very close DCT values. 
Should I make my own change to the algorithm or is there any other image comparing algorithms fits my requirement better.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing shapes, you could use [Catalano Framework](https://github.com/DiegoCatalano/Catalano-Framework). It contains several features for shape retrieval.

Hu moment and Zernike moments are good approaches for determining "good shape."